# Loop Returning Indices Instead of Actual Results?

Tags: html, r, json, loops, url

I have a list of url's in R. These are stored in a list object called "url".

I also have this loop here that I am using for webscraping. In this loop, if a specific url  takes longer than 1 second to finish the webscraping, the loop automatically moves to the next url:

```
library(R.utils)


res <- vector("list", length = 10L)

for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  tryCatch({
    res[[i]] <- withTimeout({

url_i = url[i]
        
        r_i <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
        




        res[[i]] <- r_i
        
        print(i)






    }, timeout = 1)
  }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
    message("Timeout. Skipping.")
    res[[i]] <- NULL
  })
}
```

This loop runs, but the problem is that it seems like the loop is only returning the "indices" instead of the actual webscraping results. For example:

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

Have I written this loop wrong? And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your code and since you don't provide sample data (i.e. `url`) we cannot reproduce. Also the (lack of) code formatting does not help with readability. You seem to store data in a variable `res_i` locally (within the loop); later you assign an object `r_i` to `res[[i]]` but `r_i` has not been used/defined before. This seems to be a typo? I strongly recommend fixing your formatting and cleaning up your code (lots of additional unnecessary things).

Comment: Could you provide the list of URL? That would be helpful to provide a solution.